# how to check the mocked function is called atleast once with given arguments in clojure with_redefs?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

The test I have written below won't fail if `test-service/process` is not called. And it also don't check if the URL and params are right.

```
(deftest main-func-test
    (let [event {:a 123}]
      (with-redefs
        [test-service/process (fn [url params] response)]
        (is (= :success (main/main-func event)))))
```

In ruby it's simple

```
expect(test_service).to receive(:process).with(url, params).and_return(response)
```

How can I check if `test-service/process` is called at least once with two arguments URL and params in Clojure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could capture the arguments in your mock function:

```
(deftest main-func-test
    (let [event {:a 123}
          args (atom nil)]
      (with-redefs
        [test-service/process (fn [url params] 
                                 (reset! args [url params])
                                 response)]
        (is (= :success (main/main-func event)))
        (is (= [expected-url expected-params] @args)))
```

Comment: @Ash, please don't forget to mark this question as answered!